# Create trifold in html/css

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to create a trifold print out using html/css, but I'm having a devil of a time getting the printed page to come out as I wish.

```
@page  
{ 
  size: 8.5in 11in;
  margin: 0;
}

.trifold-segment {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 2.66in;
  padding: 0.5in;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  border-right: thin dashed lightGray;
}

.trifold-segment:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border-right: none;
}
```

With this code each trifold segment should be 3.66 inches which should add up to just under 11 inches and fit neatly on an 8.5 inch by 11 inch piece of paper. Instead what I'm finding is that with these dimensions the third segment doesn't fit on the page. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there is some hidden margin that prevents me from defining the use of the full page myself.

Any insight or links to resources that might help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an RTF document with the properties that I wanted and then dynamically filled it in and offered it up as a trifold download.

Answer (score 0):

Most printers by default leave top and bottom and left and right margins when they print. Often there is a way to go full bleed (to the edge) but you'd have to Google your specific printer to find out how. Some printers don't allow this at all, so it all depends on your particular printer.

Cheers!

Cynthia